# optional std::nullopt_t implementation in libcxx

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, option-type, c++17

Clang implements `std::nullopt_t` this way:

```
struct nullopt_t
{
    explicit constexpr nullopt_t(int) noexcept {}
};

constexpr nullopt_t nullopt{0};
```

Why not simply:

```
struct nullopt_t{};

constexpr nullopt_t nullopt{};
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned on [std::nullopt_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/nullopt_t):

> **Notes**
>
> `nullopt_t` is not `DefaultConstructible` to support both `op = {};` and `op = nullopt;` as the syntax for disengaging an optional object.

Now test this with your implementation:

```
struct nullopt_t { };
template <typename T>
struct optional {
  optional &operator=(nullopt_t);
  optional &operator=(const optional &);
  optional &operator=(optional &&);
  template <typename U>
  optional &operator=(U &&);
};
int main() {
  optional<int> oi;
  oi = {};
}
```

This fails, because the call to `operator=` is ambiguous. It could be an attempt to call `operator=(nullopt_t)`, or it could be an attempt to call `operator=(optional &&)`, and there is no language rule to resolve this ambiguity.

Therefore, unless there's a change to the language rules, or `oi = {};` no longer needs to be valid, either `nullopt_t` or `optional` needs to not be default-constructible, and `nullopt_t` is the logical choice for that.

Answer (score 5):

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/nullopt_t):

> `std::nullopt_t` must be a LiteralType and cannot have a
>   default constructor. It must have a constexpr constructor that takes
>   some implementation-defined literal type.

... so if Clang implemented `nullopt_t` as you suggested, it wouldn't meet the requirements.  Now, if you are wondering why those requirements exist (a different question), the answer is:

> `nullopt_t` is not DefaultConstructible to support both `op = {};` and `op = nullopt;` as the syntax for disengaging an optional object.

Comment: That isn't the part that answers 'why'.

Comment: But *why* is there a need of a constructor that "takes some implementation-defined literal type"? Why `nullopt_t` must be a LiteralType?

Comment: @ildjarn: Yes it is.  Clang implements it that way because that is what is required.  The reason why the requirements are thus is a different question (and I have edited the answer to answer that question too.

Comment: I had this wrong in my comment as well at first, but it's no longer [`std::experimental::nullopt_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional/nullopt_t), it's planned as [`std::nullopt_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/nullopt_t) already for C++17.

Comment: "*Yes it is. Clang implements it that way because that is what is required.*" That is a useless level of pedantry. _Obviously_ 'the reason why the requirements are thus' was implicit.

Comment: @ildjarn: It wasn't at all obvious to me.  Even now you have said it, I don't think it was obvious.

Comment: @hvd: Agreed, but I'm quoting cppreference, and I feel more comfortable sticking with their wording.

Comment: cppreference has the right wording when you link to the right type, which @hvd did, in the very comment you're replying to... o_O

Comment: @ildjarn: D'oh!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Others have explained why `struct nullopt_t {};` is insufficient. But there are at least two alternative solutions that are still simpler than the ones currently ensconced in libc++ and libstdc++.

(Here's some test code: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/HnFXRjLyqi4s4ikv )

Here are the alternatives, in increasing order of paranoia:

### Option 1 (nobody as far as I know)

```
struct nullopt_t { constexpr explicit nullopt_t() {} };
constexpr nullopt_t nullopt{};
```

### Option 2 (libc++ <experimental/optional>)

```
struct nullopt_t { constexpr explicit nullopt_t(int) {} };
constexpr nullopt_t nullopt{0};
```

### Option 3 (libstdc++ <experimental/optional>)

```
struct nullopt_t {
    enum class secret { tag };
    explicit constexpr nullopt_t(secret) { }
};
constexpr nullopt_t nullopt{nullopt_t::secret::tag};
```

### Option 4 (libc++ <optional>)

```
struct nullopt_t {
    struct secret_tag { explicit secret_tag() = default; };
    constexpr explicit nullopt_t(secret_tag, secret_tag) noexcept {}
};
constexpr nullopt_t nullopt{nullopt_t::secret_tag{}, nullopt_t::secret_tag{}};
```

Any one of these alternatives (even Option 1, as far as I know) would suffice to make the assignment `o = {}` unambiguous. I don't know why both libc++ and libstdc++ go beyond that solution — and notice that libc++ goes so far as to create a *two-argument* constructor!

If anyone knows the reason for libc++'s increased paranoia, I'd love to hear it; please create an answer and/or leave a comment below.

Comment: I just had a look at libstd++'s implementation of `nullopt_t`, and was wondering why it was seemingly so verbose, eventually leading me into this thread. I kind of second your last paragraph w.r.t. non-ambiguity, but I can see why option 3 and 4 would be good in semantically prohibiting users to instantiate their own instances of `std::nullopt_t`. Attempting `std::nullopt_t my_own_nullopt{};` will yield errors on both gcc and clang, referring to candidates `explicit constexpr nullopt_t(_Construct) { }` and `constexpr explicit nullopt_t(__secret_tag, __secret_tag) noexcept {}`, respectively.

Comment: Also note that option 1 above is prohibited by [(optional.nullopt)/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/optional.nullopt): _"Type `nullopt_­t` **shall not have a default constructor** or an initializer-list constructor, and shall not be an aggregate."_